# App does not have permission: android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS

Tags: android-permissions, android-tv, android-contentresolver

I have a ContentResolver

```
contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
```

causing a

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.emptyappl/com.example.emptyappl.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.SecurityException: App does not have permission:
> android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS

Trying to grant the permission in the manifest, showed that there is no such a permission?!?!

The next permission what sounds similar

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
```

EDIT: After a possible release, I also do not want to ask each user to make some changes in the system settings. Isn't there a programatical solution?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the right path goto `Settings -> App & Notifications -> Advanced -> Special app access -> Notification access` and enable the notification for your app there.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if(notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
  // you got the permission
}else{
  Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
  startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

Comment: Edited the OP. Looking for a programatical solution..

Comment: Edited as per your requirement.